# Initial render of MTKView skewed

Tags: macos, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to adapt Apple's [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream) tutorial to MacOS (it's originally for iOS) and I've become stuck on a weird issue. It does work great on iOS. Almost all of the adapted code is the identical, except for things that don't make sense to adapt, like the depth filter. I haven't been able to find any expected differences in the documentation.

Here's the adapted project so you can it for yourself and see what I'm talking about: [AVCamFilterMacOS](https://github.com/jakeva/AVCamFilterMacOS)

What happens when I run is the MTKView's contents are skewed [image: like this]

If I resize it, it then becomes [image: what I expect]

I found that if I set the view's `autoResizeDrawable = false`, after I resize it seems to be fixed and stay fixed. But no matter what else I do, I can't seem to get the view to initialize to the expected state. It consistently renders skewed upon launch.

In addition, if I don't use the tutorial's `RosyMetalRenderer` and use its `RosyCIRenderer` instead, the problem remains. This suggests to me the shaders and transform logic of the metal renderer are not the source of the problem (which doesn't surprise me, since they're pretty simple passthrough type shaders).

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just did a build on my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015), Catalina 10.15.1 using XCode Version 11.2.1 (11B53) and don't see this issue. My build has the rose colored filter applied. Have you checked in the exact code your build is using? I see in the screenshot there is no filter applied.

Comment: Huh. Maybe it’s my laptop then? Other than that I’m on the same versions of macOS and Xcode. As for the filter, yeah I took the screenshot with that particular filter passing through all color channels just to make the preview a little easier to look at.

Comment: I'll try it on my MacBook later today and see if I get the distorted image.

Comment: Just tried this on a 2016 MacBook Pro with Radeon Pro 460 and
Intel HD Graphics 530 running macOS Catalina 10.15.1, and wasn't able to reproduce this on either device. @jakev What hardware and OS are you running on?

Comment: 2017 Macbook Pro, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650 1536 MB, MacOS 10.15.1, XCode 11.2.1 - i get the same issue no matter what I do